# TIFF IFilter not properly reading text in VARBINARY column

Tags: sql-server-2008, ocr, windows-server-2008-r2, full-text-indexing

[link text](http://www.voxtechnologies.com/SampleWorking.tif)I want to use the TIFF IFilter built in to Windows 2008 Server R2 with Full-Text search in SQL Server 2008... also R2.

I have installed the filter through server manager and updated the "Force TIFF IFilter to perform OCR for every page in a TIFF document" Local Group Policy setting in Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> OCR to "Enabled."

I have also created a full-text catalog and a table called "FileData" that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [FileServer].[FileData](
 [FileDataId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [FileGUID] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
 [Data] [varbinary](max) FILESTREAM  NOT NULL,
 [Extension] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
 [Filename] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
 [Path] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FileData_FileDataId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [FileDataId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY] FILESTREAM_ON [FILES],
 CONSTRAINT [UX_File_FileGUID] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
 [FileGUID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] FILESTREAM_ON [FILES]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [FileServer].[FileData] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_FileData_FileGUID]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [FileGUID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [FileServer].[FileData] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_FileData_FileData]  DEFAULT (0x) FOR [Data]
GO
```

When I insert a file into that table, like a PDF or word DOC, I can hit keywords in the file moments later with a fulltext search:

I made a big huge TIFF file with very clear text (1024 x 768... about 12 words) and imported THAT into the FileData table.  I can find every word in it.

```
SELECT [Path], [Filename], [Data]
FROM [FileServer].[FileData]
WHERE FREETEXT(*, 'Jason') and FREETEXT(Extension, 'tif');
```

However, when I use a "real" TIFF file, like a datasheet from a manufacturer, I get ZERO results when searching for keywords.  I do not have a clue as to why, and there is not much online troubleshooting this with SQL Server.

I have tried saving the .TIFF file with various kinds of compression, without compression, etc... and I am just not having any luck.  The text in my test file is CRYSTAL clear and still pretty large.  I cannot imagine the the file clarity is the problem, allthough I suppose that is possible.

Just so you would have something to compare, I took the following two images and imported them:

[WORKING SAMPLE FILE](http://www.voxtechnologies.com/SampleWorking.tif)
[BROKEN SAMPLE FILE](http://www.voxtechnologies.com/SampleNotWorking.tif)

**The results for the working sample are REALLY good.  These are the keywords from the working sample in the full-text index:**
$3.50
©
0004
08
1989
2010
21
21:35:42
235
282
3116
3702
40
48109
89
abounds
absorb
abstract
accompanied
acquired
act
action
advantages
agency
algorithm
algorithms
already
amounts
amsterdam
analyze
ann
appeared
applications
arbor
arnficioj
artficia1
assignment
b.v.
based
basis
booker
brigade
bucket
building
bv
capabilities
carefully
changing
characteristics
checkers
classifier
classtfier
closing
cognitive
comparing
competing
complex
complexities
complexity
computer
confronting
confuse
consider
continual
continually
continuously
contrived
credit
cures
d.e.
data
de
decent
defined
definition
design
designed
devising
discovery
discussion
disturbing
during
ecological
economic
eecs
effort
elsevier
END OF FILE
engineering
environment
environments
err
even
events
example
exhibit
experience
expressed
extant
extensions
face
faces
feasible
file
firing
first
flow
following
format
game
generates
generic
genetic
giving
goals
goldberg
good
holiadd
holland
however
hypotheses
image
immersed
immune
impinging
implicitly
inexactly
information
intelligence
interest
intervene
introduction
irrelevant
j.h.
jh
journal
l.b.
large
lb
learn
learning
lifespan
long
machine
mammal
mammalian
mammal's
massively
message
mi
michigan
new
nn0004
nn08
nn1989
nn2010
nn21
nn235
nn282
nn3116
nn3702
nn3d5$
nn40
nn48109
nn89
noisy
north
nos
novel
novelty
obtainable
often
one
operate
option
originally
outside
own
paper
parallel
passing
pattern
payoff
permission
perpetual
perpetually
play
player
plays
possible
pretty
problems
provide
publisher
publishers
quickly
randomly
rarely
real
realistic
reinforcement
repeatedly
reprinted
requirements
retina
reviews
revise
robotic
rule
rules
science
sequences
sets
significantly
simple
simply
small
sparse
system
systems
tagged
techniques
theory
thor
tiff
time
tt2135
twice
twists
two
typically
u.s.a.
university
upon
us
usa
visual
vol
without
wonder
world

**But the results from the Broken Sample are just... well, vacant.  Not a single word from the actual TIFF image:**
08
2010
21
21:49:22
END OF FILE
file
format
image
nn08
nn2010
nn21
tagged
tiff
tt2149

If anybody has any ideas on what to try next, I'm ALL ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out the actual problem was the SIZE of the image. The OCR in the ITFF IFilter just wasn't even attempting to process it... too big. I had to discover this by trial and error, and could not find any documentation stating the maximum size/DPI of the incoming TIFF. Anybody know these specs? This article appears to have some information: support.microsoft.com/kb/837847 But is specific to Sharepoint, and I have not had time to mess with the settings to see if it works. Also, I'd really need to just remove the size cap. Ideas there?

Comment: OK... My server is Server 2008 R2, and the registry keys in the aforementioned article to not even EXIST. However, I did find this value: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TiffIFilter\MaxImageSize. I'm really pretty dissappointed in the documentation on this particular IFilter... just doesn't seem to be much on its actual behaviour. It's probably fine for Sharepoint, but as a developer/SQL Admin, I need a bit more. Maybe MS will read this and update it for us.

Comment: OK, another facet to the problem.  The registry value I have is 38797312.  That should translate to about 388 MB, give or take.  The image I had posted was pretty large, but not THAT large.

Comment: The source file is 25.823 inches x 34.458 inches as 96 DPI.  Changing the DPI to 300 brings the size down to 9.163 x 12.228, but does not change the file size.  This isolates the problem to the width/height of the document as dimensions, rather than the filesize or the WxH in pixels.  I suppose I'll just convert all .TIFF files to 300 DPI on the fly, for now.  I'm already converting PDF to TIFF, so changing that value in the procoess should not be a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Try convert the non-working image to black and white, and see if more words get recognized.

**Added**

Try use IrfanView (or any image tool) to set the DPI of the second image to 300. Then try again.

Obviously, these troubleshooting steps aren't permanent solutions, they just help isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

rwong is correct.  You need to isolate the problem.

Not all OCR engines can process Color TIFF images and prefer B/W.  I am guessing that the OCR Engine is not even processing your non working page and just issues an error message you cannot see.

1. As per above try saving the file as a B/W TIFF image.
2. Save the file as a JPEG and try recognising the image as a JPEG.

I ran your non working image through my OCR and was able to extract most of the text correctly so resolution is not a major issue.

Answer (score 0):

I find something interesting

I use C# do

```
                    Image tiffFile = Image.FromFile(TiffPath);

                    resultFilePath = Path.Combine(tempFolder, Path.GetFileName(TiffPath));

                    tiffFile.Save(resultFilePath);
```

And use the put the new tiff file in database, it is work, I do not know why, but solve my problem

Comment: I find more, seems like if the tiff file compression type is LZW, there is no any problem to get the text out